# Installing gitlab on gentoo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, gentoo

I'm trying to install gitlab on my gentoo server using this unofficial guide: https://github.com/cvut/gentoo-overlay/wiki/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-6.x

I faced with 2 problems:

1. If I switch to recommended in tutorial ruby20 (using eselect) then I can't install the package at all (I created issue, see it here: https://github.com/cvut/gentoo-overlay/issues/6). Looks like dev-ruby/bundler doesn't have ruby_targets_ruby20 flag
2. If I switch to ruby19 everything went fine until I run

   emerge --config "=www-apps/gitlabhq-6.0.2-r1"

When I run this command ebuild script for some reason tries to use ruby 20 instead of ruby19 (I created issue, see it here: https://github.com/cvut/gentoo-overlay/issues/5)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for this issue. I temporarily moved /usr/bin/ruby19 to /usr/bin/ruby20. Configuration went fine. Then I rolled back /usr/bin/ruby20 to original version.

```
# cp /usr/bin/ruby20 /usr/bin/ruby20.bak
# cp /usr/bin/ruby19 /usr/bin/ruby20
# emerge --config "=www-apps/gitlabhq-6.0.2-r1"
# rm /usr/bin/ruby20
# cp /usr/bin/ruby20.bak /usr/bin/ruby20
```

Answer (score 1):

My general experience with Ruby on Gentoo (my favorite distribution so far) has been one of primarily frustration.  Almost every time a system update (via `emerge -auDN --with-bdeps=y @world`) fails due to conflicts, it's usually because of conflicting Ruby packages and dependencies.  Furthermore, the operating environment of GitLab itself is fairly complex.

I run a couple of GitLab servers, and I do so using GitLab's supplied Docker image, which is remarkably painless.

Upgrading is as simple as re-pulling the `latest` tag of the gitlab image. This is the docker command I run:

```sh
docker pull gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
docker run --detach \
           --hostname localhost \
           --publish 0.0.0.0:7080:80 --publish 0.0.0.0:7022:22 \
           --name gitlab \
           --restart always \
           --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
           --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
           --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
           gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

The task reduces, then, to installing Docker on Gentoo, which is much easier than Ruby.

In the year that I've been running a production GitLab server using docker, I've had two problems, both of which I've resolved with the single command `docker restart gitlab`.  This is the kind of thing docker was *made* for.  I'd recommend taking advantage of it.